# How to make bot send message on specific date

Tags: node.js, discord.js

i'm trying to make my discord bot send message on specific date like a birthday date i'm new to (Node.js) or (Discord.js)

this is what im trying to do

```
 client.on("ready", async () => {
  var d = new Date();
if(d.toLocaleDateString()=="7/1/2020")
birthdaychannel.send("birthday test")
 })
```

i know everything is wrong because i have no idea how to do it but is there any code similar to what im trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute code at a certain date, you'll need to ensure that either

A) Your program is running forever. Run your bot indefinitely on a server, for example, and then check the date every few seconds, and send the message on the right date. Or,

B) You can configure your computer to start your program at a certain date and just program the bot to send the message and end. **CRON Job** is the search term you want here. Of course, your computer still needs to be running to launch your program.

To help you with actual discord.js API here's an example to send a user a DM

```
const { Client } = require("discord.js");

const token = process.env.token;
const client = new Client();

client.login(token);


client.on("ready", async () => {
   const id = "3474477473288573848"; // Discord User IDs look like a long string of random numbers

  const user = await client.users.fetch(id);

  // Create/access a DM thread between the bot account and the user
  const dms = await user.createDM();

  dms.send("Happy Birthday!");

});
```

Comment: Yes, you'll want to use a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object to compare certain information about the current DateTime

Comment: sry deleted by accident

Comment: how do i use Date object

Comment: You can see the documentation for date on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: so if i make the date like this ```let birthday = new Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00')``` how do i check if it match to send the msg

Comment: btw i dont wan make the real date for birthday like i wan make it send on  specific date like he born on December 17, 1995 but i make it December 17, 2020  so it send msg on this date that would be easier

Comment: so i made new code is this works?                                                                               `client.on("ready", async () => {
 var d = new Date();
if(d.toLocaleDateString()=="7/1/2020")
birthdaychannel.send("birthday test")
 })`